# jqgrid auto sorting the data on grouped column, how can this be turned off?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with grouping, however the data coming back from the server is already grouped, I simply want to apply the jqgrid grouping look to the data.  I've included a jsfiddle since a picture speaks 1000 words.  THE DATA IS INCLUDED IN THE FIDDLE...

Link to fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Rab815/p8Zsk/

```
$('table').jqGrid({
    data: data,
    datatype: "local",
    rowNum:100,
    gridview: true,
    deepempty: true, 
    hoverrows: false, 
    headertitles: true,
    height:'600px',
    viewrecords:true,
    hoverrows: true,
    sortable: true,
    altRows: true,
    colModel: [
        { label: "Group Name", name:'groupName', field:"groupName", sortable:false},
        { label: 'Name', field: 'name', name:'name' },
        {
            label: 'Date Modified', field: 'lastGenerated', name:'lastGenerated'
        }
    ],
    grouping:true,
    groupingView:
        {
            groupField: ['groupName'],
            groupColumnShow: [true], 
            groupCollapse: true,
        },
    shrinkToFit: false
});
```

[image]

However I need it displayed in this order

[image]

Now, if you put the data in an editor so each block appears on one line, the data is already coming back grouped from the DB in the order I want it to appear.  but the grid is sorting the groupName data field in 'asc' order and far as I can tell it can't be turned off.

The Grouping Column would eventually be set to groupColumnShow: [false]

**ANSWER from Olegs FIDDLE...**

Included a

> groupOrder

in the data coming from the server rather than doing the mapping.

Altered ColModel for GroupName as follows

```
{
    label: "Group Name", field: "groupName",
    sorttype: function (cellValue, obj) {
                    return obj.groupOrder;
                    //return groupOrder[obj.groupId];
}
```

Now everything appears in the correct order.  This solution allows the sort, which defaults to "asc" in jqgrid to order the grouped data by a different value other than the grouped data itself.

Thanks!  This had me stumped for quite a while!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem exist because you use `datatype: "local"` with the data loaded from the server.

To solve your problem you can define `sorttype` property as function in the column "groupName" by which you sort. The function should return the value which can be used **instead of** the column value. For example you can extend the items of the data with new field `groupOrder` for example and use

```
sorttype: function (cellValue, obj) {
    return groupOrder[obj.groupId];
}
```

The field should be filled on the server.

Alternatively you can fill the map between `groupId` in your current data model and the index to the group order. For example the code

```
var groupOrder = {}, i, l = data.length, groupId, groupIndex = 1;

for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    groupId = data[i].groupId;
    if (groupOrder[groupId] === undefined) {
        groupOrder[groupId] = groupIndex++;
    }
}
```

fills `groupOrder` in the same order in which you have the groups (you can use `data[i].groupName` instead of `data[i].groupId` in the same way). Having such `groupOrder` you can use

```
sorttype: function (cellValue, obj) {
    return groupOrder[obj.groupId];
}
```

The demo http://jsfiddle.net/p8Zsk/38/ use the approach and it displays the groups in correct order.